# Horizontal form with bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a fluid one-row form with text boxes, with each textbox having its corresponding label on top of it.  Just like a table with a header and only one data-row, something roughly like this (but hopefully prettier...):
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5553/

The form should preferably be fluid, so that the text boxes resize as needed (but the labels should always stay on top of their respective textbox).

Here is one unsuccessful attempt:
http://jsfiddle.net/fJ7Hb/3/

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-sm-1">Item #</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
        <label class="col-sm-1">Description</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
        <label class="col-sm-1">Qty</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
        <label class="col-sm-1">Price</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
        <label class="col-sm-1">Total</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each of your columns in a div tag and then work with some css elements to set display and where you want each item.

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fJ7Hb/6/

### HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <label class="col-sm-1">Item #</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="col-sm-1">Description</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="col-sm-1">Qty</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="col-sm-1">Price</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="col-sm-1">Total</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.row {
    width: 1100px;
}

.row > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: My CSS skills are very limited, so I am not sure how to turn your fiddle into something that looks closer to what I described.

Comment: @JimBalo CSS is very simple. What I gave you, I don't think it is that great, but it is a good place to start. You can mess around with positioning and things. You will need to create a CSS file `someFile.css` and when you want to style for a class it is `.class` and when you want to style for an id it is `#id`

Comment: To make it look the way described, properly aligned and fluid is above my CSS skills.  Perhaps you can show me a working example with my simple four fields?